# Java (Android), method POST, web-format instead of JSON

Tags: java, android, json, rest, post

I have the code

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Current-Version", "v1");

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("email", "test@test.test");
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = 
new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

HttpEntity<Login> response = getRestTemplate().exchange(
    url,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    request ,
    Login.class
);
```

and this works good, but on the server side I get BODY of request in format JSON, although web-format is `param1=val1&param2=val2`. And I have to send post request to server in format `param1=val1&param2=val2`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use below method.

```
public static String getPostDataString(HashMap<Object, Object> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey().toString()));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue().toString()));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

**Usage**

```
   try{  
        String requestJSON = getPostDataString(inputData);
   }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Put all data in `HashMap` and pass `HashMap` in this method you will get request string in **param1=val1&param2=val2** format.

**Example.**

```
HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("email", "test@test.test");
map.put("password", "testtest");
map.put("type", "1");
```

Now pass above `HashMap` in method.

String requestString = "";

```
try{
     requestString = getPostDataString(map);
}catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will get request string in below format.

**`"email=test@test.test&password=testtest&type=1"`**

Answer (score 0):

in exchnage method there are 3 more parameters which you can pass,

```
requestEntity - the entity (headers and/or body) to write to the request, may be null
responseType - the type of the return value
uriVariables - the variables to expand in the template
```